# Kubernetes Pod Security Policy Default Privileged Value

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning more about Kubernetes Pod Security Policies, and while going through the list of fields, I could not find the default value for the [Privileged](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged) flag. Is this value dependent on the container runtime used? For example, [Docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) have this value set to false by default, so if I had a Kubernetes cluster with only Docker containers, would all the pods be unprivileged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a fresh cluster the default PSP is very permissive which means that you pretty much anything is allowed. So the default would be to allow privileged containers if the privileged flag was toggled on the pod, same with root users, etc.

You will have to explicitly turn set the flag to true in the PSP if you want to enforce it. I believe this is true regardless of the Container runtime being used, works with Windows containers too :)

Comment: getting a conflicting answer from @yasin

Comment: I agree with what @yasin was saying in regards to the SecurityContext of the Pod. The default PodSecurityPolicy is just not set to enforce that, so you could have privileged containers running unless you set that flag in the PSP same goes for containers running as root.

Comment: I see, thanks. Weird that the security context defaults to unprivileged, but PSPs do not.

Answer (score 2):

There is a privileged flag on the SecurityContext of the container spec. The default is false.

Foreexample by below template you can set it to true.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hello-world-container
      # The container definition
      # ...
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

Comment: right, but I'm specifically asking about Pod Security Policies. Would it be the same defaults? I checked the documentation here, and it does not say what the default is, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#podsecuritypolicyspec-v1beta1-policy

Comment: I think if you test it you can understand the defaults.what do you think?

Comment: every container by default do not have privilege. I think all container you have make by kubernetes are un privileged.